# Flatten JSON data using pandas json_normalize

Tags: python, json, pandas

Here is my json file looks like:

```
{"File": "xyz.csv", "Line": "0", "Classes": [{"Name": "ABC", "Score": 0.9842}, {"Name": "DEF", "Score": 0.0128}, {"Name": "GHI", "Score": 0.003}]}
{"File": "xyz.csv", "Line": "1", "Classes": [{"Name": "ABC2", "Score": 0.9999}, {"Name": "DEF2", "Score": 0.1111}, {"Name": "GHI2", "Score": 0.5666}]}

pred_df = pd.read_json('filename.json',lines=True)
```

When I tried to use json_normalize the last column "Classes", it give me an error: string indices must be integers

```
Class = json_normalize(data = pred_df,
                  record_path= pred_df['Classes'],
                  meta =['Name','Score'])
```

Pls let me know what I'm missing here....thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this in two steps. The first loads your JSON, the second then flattens your "Classes" column and broadcasts the rest of your data to it using `np.repeat`.

```
df = pd.read_json('filename.json', lines=True)

classes = df.pop('Classes')
pd.concat([
    pd.DataFrame(classes.sum()), 
    pd.DataFrame(df.values.repeat(classes.str.len(), axis=0), columns=[*df])
], axis=1)

   Name   Score     File Line
0   ABC  0.9842  xyz.csv    0
1   DEF  0.0128  xyz.csv    0
2   GHI  0.0030  xyz.csv    0
3  ABC2  0.9999  xyz.csv    1
4  DEF2  0.1111  xyz.csv    1
5  GHI2  0.5666  xyz.csv    1
```

Replace `classes.sum()` with `itertools.chain.from_iterable(classes)` if performance is important.